# How to save collections of objects and use them in c++ vector

Tags: c++

I need to use a vector that has a type of MyClass.

```
vector<MyClass> vMyClass;
vMyClass.Push_Back(new MyClass);
```

This does not seem to work for me. What is going wrong? I am trying to simulate a List like in C#.

I then need to perform an action on all items in the list. Like in C# foreach item in vMyClass.

I have looked everywhere for a simple example of this and have had no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new MyClass` returns a pointer to a `MyClass`, but your vector contains objects, not pointers.

Try

```
vMyClass.push_back(MyClass());
```

or, if you need dynamic memory

```
vector<MyClass*> vMyClass;
```

with your version. Note the all-lower-case `push_back`.

Comment: And then how do i itterate through them and perform an action on each MyClass object.

Comment: @JonathanO I can see how the initial problem might have been difficult to google, but iterating over a vector should turn up pretty easily.

Comment: @JonathanO - you should look up iterators.